# How can I center a div inside a div within a container?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using the Materialize CSS front end framework and using margin: 0 auto; as I always have, and having a nightmare getting this div centered within its parent. What gives?

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:100px;
}

.inner{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:50px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row outer">
    <div class="col l6 inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/kinsdotnet/pen/mEYJVg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materialise uses a grid system that floats elements. You can't use `margin: auto` on a floated element.

You'll need to either use offset classes form the grid, or  rearrange the grid and that child element...

(http://codepen.io/jmsherry/pen/OXYVRL <-- like that)

Also, don't listen to the really bad advice of !important and Absolute positioning. There are better ways to do this...

Answer (score 0):

## Absolute inside Relative

Set the position of the outer div to relative, the inner to absolute.

To make `margin: 0px auto` work, add `left: 0; right:0;`

**Also** you must specify width to the inner div.

if you want to center vertically,

just replace:

```
margin: 0px auto
```

with:

```
margin: auto
```

### Result:

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}

.inner{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:50px;
  margin: 0px auto;

  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row outer">
    <div class="col l6 inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your inner class:

```
float:none !important;
```

it looks like the class col applies a float left, and that's why it doesn't center